# sculpting on the wrong side

Tags: sculpting

[image]

Using the clay strips with default settings on the front of the object causes the back of the mesh to be also edited by brush

problem seems to be most noticeable with the clay strips

blend file:

https://pasteall.org/blend/e83a6bd28dc64bf58626de06007bffe0

object doesnt have any modifiers

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mesh is too thin. Select *Front Faces Only* under [Brush Settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/brush_settings.html). From the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/brush_settings.html):

> When enabled, the brush only affects vertices that are facing the viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Enable the *Plane Trim* option under [Brush Settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/brush_settings.html?highlight=plane%20trim):

[image]

Turning on *Front Faces Only* [as mentioned in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229320/31447) also works and might be a better solution.

Comment: turning on front faces only (like the other answers say) also works and might be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Turning ON "Front Faces Only" in brush settings will solve your problem.

Sculpt brushes sometimes catch back geometry for thin meshes.

[image]